# C# Culture and Java Locale mismatch

Tags: c#, java, locale, culture

Consider this comparison:

```
String a = "\u00C4";       // "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"
String b = "\u0041\u0308"; // "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A" and "COMBINING DIAERESIS"
```

Comparing these in C# Danish culture, returns false:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false);
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b, StringComparison.CurrentCulture));   // false
```

Comparing these in Java Danish locale, returns true:

```
System.out.println(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("Danish (Denmark)").equals(a,b)); // true
```

I have listed all locales/cultures in both environments and have confirmed that the right ones are selected. Am I missing something? What's with the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your results using .NET 4:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String a = "\u00C4";
        String b = "\u0041\u0308";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b, StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
    }
}
```

That program prints "True" for me. Does the exact same program print "False" for you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using .NET 2.0. I tried 3.0, 3.5 and still false. Changing to 4.0 produces true. Not cool.

Comment: It's not bad.  All you have to do is upgrade to the latest version to fix your problem.  This is good.